# Generic function using Diesel causes overflow

Tags: generics, rust, rust-diesel

I have an API written in Rust and it's goal is to expose ~15 tables in a database. I've written several very similar functions to expose each table so I thought I'd take a crack at polymorphism to simplify the code.

I've reduced all the code to a single file:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate dotenv;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

table! {
    table1 (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        value -> Text,
    }
}

table! {
    table2 (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        value -> Text,
    }
}

#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Serialize)]
#[table_name = "table1"]
struct Model1 {
    pub id: i32,
    pub value: String,
}

#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable, Serialize)]
#[table_name = "table2"]
struct Model2 {
    pub id: i32,
    pub value: String,
}

use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

fn get_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();
    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url).expect("Database not working")
}

use diesel::QueryDsl;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::query_dsl::LoadQuery;
use diesel::result::Error;
use diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FindDsl;
use serde::Serialize;
use serde_json::to_string;

fn get_row<'a, Model, Table>(table: Table, id: i32) -> Result<String, Error>
where
    Table: QueryDsl,
    <Table as FindDsl<i32>>::Output: LoadQuery<PgConnection, Model>,
    Model: Serialize,
{
    let result: Model = table.find(id).load(&get_connection())?;
    Ok(to_string(&result)?)
}

fn main() {
    let row1 = get_row::<Model1, _>(table1::table, 1);
    let row2 = get_row::<Model2, _>(table2::table, 1);
}
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file

```toml
[package]
name = "question"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "*", features = ["postgres"] }
diesel_codegen = "*"
serde = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
serde_json = "*"
dotenv = "*"
```

When I try to run this, I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<Table as diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<_>>::Output`
  --> src/main.rs:54:1
   |
54 | / fn get_row<'a, Model, Table>(table: Table, id: i32) -> Result<String, Error>
55 | | where
56 | |     Table: QueryDsl,
57 | |     <Table as FindDsl<i32>>::Output: LoadQuery<PgConnection, Model>,
...  |
61 | |     Ok(to_string(&result)?)
62 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
```

The compiler tells me that I might resolve the issue by increasing the recursion limit, but I tried doing that up to 8096 and the error still wasn't resolved.

Comment: Thank you for providing a reasonable, small, complete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You weren't far off:

```
use diesel::dsl::Find;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::query_dsl::{LoadQuery, RunQueryDsl};
use diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FindDsl;
use diesel::result::Error;

fn get_row<'a, Model, Table>(table: Table, id: i32) -> Result<String, Error>
where
    Table: FindDsl<i32>,
    Find<Table, i32>: LoadQuery<PgConnection, Model>,
{
    let conn = get_connection();
    let result = table.find(id).load::<Model>(&conn)?;
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Points to note:

1. Diesel has a bunch of helper type aliases which make writing trait bounds easier. Here, the `Find` alias has been used.
2. It can be more obvious to use more specific trait bounds instead of less specific ones. Here, switching to `FindDsl` instead of `QueryDsl` is probably what makes the code compile. `QueryDsl` doesn't mean that you can call `find` as the [`QueryDsl::find` method actually has further trait bounds](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.1.1/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.find):

   ```
   fn find<PK>(self, id: PK) -> Find<Self, PK>
   where
       Self: FindDsl<PK>,
   ```
3. The return value of `load` is a `Vec` of results, but you had annotated the type as a single value. Perhaps you wanted to use `get_result` or `first` instead?
4. I removed the Serde-specific code because there's no obvious way to convert the Serde error to a Diesel error; that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks! I switched to get_result like you suggested. It does make more sense :)